# htaccess Removed File Extension Yet Extension Still Exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using htaccess, I was able to make my html urls function without a file extension, yet the file extension still exists. For example:

example.com/index
AND
example.com/index.html
BOTH exist!

I ONLY want my html file urls to exist at the single stripped url
(e.g. example.com/index )

I've tried manually deleting the .html off of my files, but then the files will simply load as plain text. What can I do to achieve the results I want?

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite doesn't actually remove the extension. It just allows you to not use it and internally rewrites to it in the rule. Also you can't manually make the file extension disappear. It has to be there for it to work. So in addition to your current rule you need to check the request and redirect to the extensionless URL if they enter `.html` on it. Use this rule and let me know how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^&\ ]+).html
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: That works great, and I could very well just stick to this. However, out of curiosity, there must be something else I'm not understanding. theoatmeal.com has pages with no file extension. I checked the source and it's xhtml. I tried manually adding .html to his pages and unlike with this code, it wouldn't redirect, it'd 404! On the chance he was being sneaky with his coding, I also tried adding .php to his pages, but still it'd 404! How is he able to have no file extension on his pages!?

Comment: Honestly there are so many tricks, I'm not sure what he's doing. He could actually be using folders, or ajax for his pages. You can even make is so if they enter in .html or some extension it returns 404 instead of redirecting. Personally I'd rather it just redirect so they at least still get the correct page.

Comment: Side note, They are using cakePHP. And the 404 that is returned is not from apache but looks like from PHP code. So it's probably in the coding and maybe using some SEO plugin. Could be anything.

Comment: I thought the same thing, that it'd be better to just redirect than make it 404. The owner of that site's expertise was SEO before he became a successful content creator, so I reckon he has a purpose. I can only imagine he really REALLY wants canonization for SEO and thus takes extra measures to make sure different urls for the same page don't exist.

Comment: If its any consolation doing what you're doing prevents duplicates as well because it will always refer back to the extension less URL with the redirect. That's why it's 301 redirect. So you are good.

Comment: One more thing, now my htaccess code to redirect incorrect links to my custom 404 page isn't working since adding this code. Any idea why?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[a-z.]+)example.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule . http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]